# Transmitting newline character "\n"

Tags: url, html-entities, html-encode

Given the following URL (working, try it!)

> https://select-test.wp3.rbsworldpay.com/wcc/purchase?instId=151711&cartId=28524&currency=GBP&amount=1401.49&testMode=100&name=Tom%20Gul&address=24%20House%20Road\nSome
>   Place\nCounty&postcode=TR33%20999&email=email@mail.com&country=GB

If you click on the link and go through to the payment page, the address in the address box is not displaying properly, the newline characters are displaying as text.

I've tried passing through `<br />'s` but no luck, anyone got any ideas?  I need to get  the address to display with newlines.

Commas are OK as a separator but i would much prefer being able to have newlines.  Thanks for any help!  A working example will be the accepted answer.

Comment: You need to get the address to display where?

Comment: is there any function which encode html entities in this way ?

Answer (score 473, accepted):

Try using `%0A` in the URL, just like you've used `%20` instead of the space character.

Comment: @enumiro Can you tell me how to send character ' i.e. single quotes

Comment: To send the single Quote char just use: %27

Comment: `%0A` for newline `\n` <LF>` ; and `%0D` for carriage return `\r` <CR>

Comment: Here is the list of Encoding Reference characters: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP

Comment: This is not for HTML or URL but in C# `&#010;` - it might be useful,  - https://articles.runtings.co.uk/2009/10/secret-newline-symbol-for-html-encoded.html

Answer (score 56):

Try to replace the `\n` with `%0A` just like you have spaces replaced with `%20`.

Answer (score 31):

Use `%0A` (URL encoding) instead of `\n` (C encoding).

Answer (score 20):

late to the party, but if anyone comes across this, javascript has a [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) method

Comment: FYI: `encodeURI('\n')` returns `%0A` (tested on Google Chrome v89.0.4389.114)

Answer (score 1):

Replace the \n with %0A.

That's all.

Comment: Looks like this exact answer was already provided. 12 years ago.