# New Line on PHP Header

Tags: php

How to **insert String with new line** on a header with php? Below are the codes that I did,

```
$error = "Not enough balance to submit. \nBalance available : " . $balance;
header('location:info-page.php?error=' . $error);
```

When I submit, it will give this error:

```
Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected.
```

---

> **UPDATE CODES**

```
$error = urlencode("Not enough balance to submit. \nBalance available : ". $baki_cuti);
header('location:permohonan_maklumat_penyelia.php?id='.$pid.'&error='. $error));
```

**Page : permohonan_maklumat_penyelia.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
        alert("' .urldecode($_GET['error']) . '");
    </script>';
}
?>
```

Error received:

```
permohonan_maklumat_penyelia.php?id=842&error=Not+enough+balance+to+submit.+
Balance+available+%3A+0:112 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Comment: Your question might meet [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871729/transmitting-newline-character-n)

Comment: Thanks for the reference @alariva. May I know how to apply it on the string? I tried to replace \n with %0A but the it will ouptut the %0A not as new line.

Comment: check wrapping your output with urldecode(): `echo urldecode($string);` and if you require also use htmlentities(): `echo htmlentities(urldecode($string));` The answer of @flauntster should help as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to encode whatever string you like to be appended to the URL. And the receiving script could use [urldecode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) to decode that string.

eg:

```
$error = urlencode("Not enough balance to submit. \nBalance available : $balance");
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I tried to use urlencode and urldecode but it give error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Comment: Weird - could you post your code that generated that error?