# How to add line-break in the google groups description field?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I tried several ways to add line-breaks in the google groups description field while creating the group using the Google directory api. https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/groups/insert
Ex: \n, \r\n, &#10 etc.

But none of the worked.

Please let me know if you have any other option.

Thanks

Comment: You state you have "tried several ways" but don't mention a single one of them. Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It is a very good questions. And so annoying that Google Groups does not allow linebreaks - unbelievable. I hope Google buys Stackoverflow soon (or their software) to provide a much better QA site.

Answer (score 0):

The last thing you can try is to [URI encode the '\n'](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) using `%0A`. This seems to have been successfully used in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871729/transmitting-newline-character-n).