# Newline characters in String query parameter

Tags: spring-boot, restful-url

I want to add newline characters in query parameters for a get method in my RESTful API.

This is my final `GET` URL in Postman:-

```
www.localhost:8091/customRule?someString="this is some string \\n on new line"
```

I get the exception:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the request target [/customRule?someString=%22this%20is%20some%20string%20\\n%20on%20new%20line%22]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
```

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Does this help you? It suggests using %0A. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871729/transmitting-newline-character-n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read a few things about this topic, but decided that there is not exactly the answer you are looking for. But something like this came to my mind.
In `Java`, the new line character is '`\n`'.

We need to encode the new line character [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3871729/transmitting-newline-character-n).

I tried with a little code like this:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/new")
public ResponseEntity<?> newLineCharacter(@RequestParam("newline") String newLine) {
    String s = new StringBuilder("xxx").append(newLine).append("yyy").toString();
    log.info(s);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

When I trigger this url with the encoded new line character `%0A` as follows:

> localhost:8080/a/new?newLine=%0A

I see an output like this in my logs:

> xxx
>
> yyy

But there seems to be an important point to note here,
In `Linux`, `Windows` or `Mac` environments, the new line character is **different**.

You can see the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426397/do-line-endings-differ-between-windows-and-linux).

Therefore, using the new line character as my query param did not seem to me a very good idea.

I hope this helps you.